# How do i import these functions? Attribute Error

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

I just began studying python and created a simple calculator GUI with python and tkinter. The Buttons work but for some reason when i try to move the functions to another file and import them it doesnt work and i get an AttributeError.

Mainfile:

```
from tkinter import *
from functions_calc_advanced import *

if _name_ == "_main_":

    gui = Tk()
    gui.configure(background="white")
    gui.title("LABINF Calculator WSS2018")
    gui.geometry("400x200")

    equation = StringVar()

    expression_field = Entry(gui, textvariable=equation)
    expression_field.grid(columnspan=4, ipadx=10)
    equation.set('enter your expression')
```

The window opens but when i press any button i get an error. This button1 is just an example all the other buttons are structured the same way

```
    button1 = Button(gui, text=' 1 ',command=lambda: press(1), height=1, width=7)
    button1.grid(row=4, column=0)

    buttonauf = Button(gui, text=' ( ', fg='black', bg='grey',command=lambda: press('('), height=1, width=7)
    buttonauf.grid(row=5, column=0)

    buttonzu = Button(gui, text=' ) ', fg='black', bg='grey',command=lambda: press(')'), height=1, width=7)
    buttonzu.grid(row=6, column=0)

    buttondot = Button(gui, text=' . ', fg='black', bg='grey',command=lambda: press('.'), height=1, width=7)
    buttondot.grid(row=5, column=2)

    buttonquit = Button(gui, text="Quit", command = gui.destroy, bg = 'black', fg = "white")
    buttonquit.grid(row = 0, column = 4)
```

Calculation Buttons

```
    plus = Button(gui, text=' + ', fg='orange', bg='white', command=lambda: press("+"), height=1, width=2)
    plus.grid(row=2, column=3)

    minus = Button(gui, text=' - ', fg='orange', bg='white', command=lambda: press("-"), height=1, width=2)
    minus.grid(row=3, column=3)

    mult = Button(gui, text=' * ', fg='orange', bg='white', command=lambda: press("*"), height=1, width=2)
    mult.grid(row=4, column=3)

    div = Button(gui, text=' / ', fg='orange', bg='white', command=lambda: press("/"), height=1, width=2)
    div.grid(row=5, column=3)

    equal = Button(gui, text=' = ', fg='white', bg='orange', command=equalpress, height=1, width=7)
    equal.grid(row=6, column=3)

    clear = Button(gui, text='C', fg='white', bg='black', command=clear, height=1, width=7)
    clear.grid(row=0, column=3)

    gui.mainloop()
```

Functions file i am trying to import from:

```
expression = ""
equation = ""
def press(num):
    global expression
    expression = expression + str(num)
    equation.set(expression)

def equalpress():
    try:
        global expression
        total = str(eval(expression))
        equation.set(total)
        expression = ""

    except: 
        equation.set(" error ")
        expression = ""

def clear():
    global expression
    expression = ""
    equation.set("")
```

Comment: Please also show a trace of the error you get along with the line number etc

Answer (score 1):

String doesn't have `set` attribute, so you should change your function file that you are trying to import to this code:

```
expression = ""
equation = ""

def press(num):
    global expression, equation
    expression = expression + str(num)
    equation = expression

def equalpress():
    global expression, equation
    try:
        total = str(eval(expression))
        equation = total
        expression = ""

    except: 
        equation = " error "
        expression = ""

def clear():
    global expression, equation
    expression = ""
    equation = ""
```

You should change `equation.set` to `equation = "..."` because `str` type doesn't have `set` attribute

Comment: Thanks for the response! I changed my functions file and i dont get the errorcode anymore!